# Image goes out of my column using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am not using css for styles but I have bootstrap 3*. I created a column that handles my form. I want to place my image just below it but when I render the image, it goes out the column. 
[image]

This is how I code it in the .html

```
<div class="col-md-3" *ngIf="showForm">
    <mat-card>
      <mat-card-content>
        <form [formGroup]="form">
          .
          .
          .
          .
          .
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <mat-form-field>
                <mat-select
                  placeholder="Baranggay"
                  formControlName="BarangayCode"
                >
                  <mat-option
                    *ngFor="let b of barangayList"
                    [value]="b.BarangayCode"
                  >
                    {{ b.BarangayName }}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input
            type="file"
            class="form-control"
            accept="image/*"
            (change)="changeListener($event)"
          />
          <button
            mat-raised-button
            type="submit"
            class="btn btn-danger pull-right"
            [disabled]="form.invalid"
            (click)="updateProperty()"
          >
            Update Property
          </button>
          <button
            mat-raised-button
            type="submit"
            class="btn btn-warning pull-right"
            (click)="onCancel()"
          >
            Cancel
          </button>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>

          <div
            *ngIf="base64Image"
            class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"
          >
            <img
              *ngIf="base64Image"
              [src]="
                domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(base64Image)
              "
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
```

Could you please show me how to do this right? Thank you.

Comment: add class to img "img-responsive"

Comment: @LaljiTadhani I did that Sir. Still a no go..

Comment: Try setting image's `max-width: 100%` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly then try setting this:

```
.img-responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```